# upload video via youtube android api , using intend like uploaddemointent example

Tags: android-intent, youtube-api

i try to use this code to upload video to youtube

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null).setType("video/*");
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

and on onActivityResult i put this :

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
switch (requestCode) {
 case SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST:

Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createUploadIntent(this, returnedIntent.getData());
startActivity(intent);}}
```

exactly like the example in the api demonstrate

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents

but when i try to upload video from my device it's look ilke start uplod but stack, write waiting ...

any advice ???

thanks ahead

Comment: solved.  the problem was from YouTube Settings to solve this need go to setting => upload => select all the Networks